# Pulse audio not working

Tags: package-management, pulseaudio, dependencies, indicator-sound

I was playing a video on youtube and suddenly there was no sound I clicked on settings--audio---and see everything greyed out.so I uninstalled pulse audio and was successfully uninstalled.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'pulseaudio' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded
```

I removed the audio control Icon also.when I try to reinstall I get the following error message:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pulseaudio : Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3) but 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

can you help me in this regard.

Thank you Mark the solution worked perfectly.

Comment: Most likely you need to run `sudo apt update` first to get an updated list of available packages.

Comment: If the above comment does not work try  `sudo apt autoremove && apt update`.